# Remove row from JQuery Accordion then remove row from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to remove a row from the accordion in JQuery then update my db with the removal. So far the removal of the row in the accordion works fine. I am then trying to get the index of the removed row and post it back to the same page so that it can run a MySQL query to remove the row in the db and then reload the accordion from the db now that the row has been removed.

My JavaScript is limited so I don't think I'm passing the index properly?

Thanks for the help.

```
 <?PHP    
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 $id = intval($_POST['id']);
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM `$db_name`.`$tbl_3` WHERE id='$id'");
 unset($_POST['id']);
 header("Location: ".$siteurl."messenger.php");
 }
 ?>


<SCRIPT>
$(function(){
$( "#inbox" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    icons: { "header": "ui-icon-plus", "headerSelected": "ui-icon-minus" },
    active: false
});

$('#myClicker').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('DIV');
    var head = parent.prev('DIV');
    parent.add(head).fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
            var index = jQuery(this).find("H4").index(ui.newHeader[0]);
    $.post('messenger.php', { id: index }, function(data) {});
});
});


</SCRIPT>
```

This is how I'm displaying the data from the db.

```
<DIV id="inbox">
    <?PHP
      $sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbl_3` ORDER BY id DESC";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
      {
    ?>
    <DIV>
        <H4><A href="#"><?PHP echo "".$row[3]."";?></A></H4>
    </DIV>
    <DIV>
        <P><?PHP echo "".$row[4]."";?></P>
        <INPUT type="button" id="myClicker" value="delete"/>
    </DIV>

    <?PHP
    }
    ?>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injections](http://at.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)! (though doing intval and alike is already good IMO)

Comment: if you remove it with JS what would you want to reload it from DB? just save the new value and next time you load the page you'll get the data you need.

Comment: Maybe my JS is off but what kind of function is "function(event, ui){}" there is no name declared... and when is it called?

Comment: If I could run the MySQL from JS I wouldn't need to reload the page. yes.

Comment: that function is to get the index to post it back I think it is suppose to run on the delete click.

Comment: Ive taken out the function and moved the code, the UI loads now but still does not remove from db.. Also it only removes the top row in the accordion it won't let me delete any other.. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I use a totally different method for these kind of things.

What I do is make a php function/file that compiles the accordeon, menu, table, div for me, when I need it updated I simple reload the contents of the container div with an ajax call to the generator.

That way I take all the guesswork out of it, and only need to pass one value to the php script. This script could then also do the database stuff.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was trying to do. But it's all on the same page. It also only passes one value to the PHP script, only difference is you are reloading the div and I am reloading the page. At the end of the day I still need to get the clicked index and use it in my db query, so how do you get your clicked index to your php page? I don't see any guesswork?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#myClicker').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('DIV');
    var head = parent.prev('DIV');
    var index = parent.prev('DIV').find("H4").index(ui.newHeader[0]);
    parent.add(head).fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});

    $.post('messenger.php', { id: index }, function(data) {});
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks will try this just now and get back to you.